# Octave: plot rectangle with dashed lines

Tags: plot, octave

I am trying to plot a rectangle with dashed lines in Octave, but if I add the property ":" with "linestyle" before it,the plot lines remain solid.
What am I doing wrong?
There are several ways to plot a rectangle. Please tell me one that works, that's all I need.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you provide a code snippet, which someone can copy and paste?

Comment: Btw, it works for me.

Comment: @Andy, what works for you? Just give me the code, that's all I need.

Comment: @Andy, problem was that I had switched on "gnuplot" as plot tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear ; close all; clc;
figure('Position',[0,0,600,600]);
rectangle("position", [1,1,3,3], "linestyle", "--")
zoom(0.5)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I [couldn't resist!](https://media.giphy.com/media/gawAL8Xum5U3K/giphy.gif)